# Export SharePoint calendar to excel in same calendar format

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar, export-to-excel, calendar-view

I want to export the calendar list into excel, I am aware of list ribbon - export to excel.

Its exporting all events in list format,
I want the exported excel to be in month view with all the dates and events in that.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better way and I probably don't have the best answer. However, I have done this before and it's an option.

Write a PowerShell script to convert the csv to json. Then use the json objects to create a new csv in the format you want for the output of the script.

Json is actually really easy to work with in powershell or python if that's your thing.

Here is a link that might help. http://brianvanderplaats.com/2015/10/08/generating-json-from-csv-using-powershell/

You would just have to run the csv through the script real quick every time you generate it from SharePoint.

Again, I know this probably isn't the best answer, but I just figured I would drop my 2 cents in the pot incase it helps someone.

P.s. Anytime you can get a CSV and manipulate it in programmatic loops through json objects, you basically have superpowers especially if your using something like matplotlib for python. You can make really awesome metrics and things and it's a lot more flexible than excel with a not-to-steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

No. Excel is a software for spreadsheets and it does not recognize “calendar view”, so any data will be imported as tables and rows of data.

You should be looking into other solutions without using Excel, a client application that supports calendar view (*Outlook*, for example). Or consider using custom solutions like the other Answer mentioned.